# Parsing date without month using DateTimeFormatter

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

I try to parse a date with this format: `ddYYYY`. For example, I have the string `141968`, and I want to know that `day = 14` and `year = 1968`.

I suppose I have to use directly a `TemporalAccessor` gave by `DateTimeFormatter.parse(String)`, but I cannot find how to use this result. While debugging I see the result is a `java.time.Parsed` which is not public but contains informations I want in field `fieldValues`.

How can I parse this particular format?

Thank you.

Comment: `new SimpleDateFormat("ddyyyy").parse("141968")`?

Comment: @MadProgrammer - I guess you can probably post that as an actual answer

Comment: Is there a way to do this with java.time package?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One approach is to default the missing month field:

```
DateTimeFormatter f = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
  .appendPattern("ddyyyy")
  .parseDefaulting(MONTH_OF_YEAR, 1)
  .toFormatter();
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("141968", f);
System.out.println(date.getDayOfMonth());
System.out.println(date.getYear());
```

Another is to query the `TemporalAccessor`:

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ddyyyy");
TemporalAccessor parsed = f.parse("141968");
System.out.println(parsed.get(ChronoField.YEAR));
System.out.println(parsed.get(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

(Note the use of "y", not "Y" for parsing)

Answer (score 2):

`YYYY` produces a WeakBasedYear field which cannot be accessed that easily (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns) from `TemporalAccessor`.
You have to use the pattern "ddyyyy" or "dduuuu" with `DateTimeFormatter` to use `ChronoField.YEAR`:

```
TemporalAccessor parsed = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ddyyyy").parse("141968");
System.out.println(parsed.get(ChronoField.YEAR));
System.out.println(parsed.get(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

Output:

> 1968
>   14

Answer (score -1):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("ddyyyy");
Date DateToStr = sdf.parse("141968");// To convert to date Date object
sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/yyyy"); // Separating by '/'
System.out.println(sdf.format(DateToStr));
```

output 14/1968

Comment: Added explanation in comments.Thanks.

Comment: When the question asked for a modern `DateTimeFormatter`, please don’t suggest the troublesome and long outdated `SImpleDateFormat`.