# Generic date parsing in java

Tags: java, date, date-format

I have date strings in various formats like Oct 10 11:05:03 or 12/12/2016 4:30 etc
If I do

```
// some code...
getDate("Oct 10 11:05:03", "MMM d HH:mm:ss");
// some code ...
```

The date gets parsed, but I am getting the year as 1970 (since the year is not specified in the string.) But I want the year as current year if year is not specidied. Same applies for all fields.

here is my getDate function:

```
public Date getDate(dateStr, pattern) {
    SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern); 
    Date date = parser.parse(myDate);
    return date;
}
```

can anybody tell me how to do that inside getDate function (because I want a generic solution)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should take a look at the Java 8 Time API. The `Date` class is considered obsolete and has been superseded by the classes from `java.time`.

Comment: In addition to what @MCEmperor says, `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` from java.time has a `parseDefaulting` method for specifying for example the year you want of no year can be found in the parsed string.

Comment: You never showed us what the timestamps look like which actually _do_ have a year present.  Please include this information in your question, thanks.

Comment: I think your heading down an unhealthy avenue. You will have a *lot* of trouble first specifying which format pattern strings are allowed and what they mean, and next validating that the actual format pattern string adheres to the specification.

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not know the format in advance, you should list the actual formats you are expecting and then try to parse them. If one fails, try the next one.

[Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29644949/parsing-date-without-month-using-datetimeformatter) of how to fill in the default.

You'll end up with something like this:

```
DateTimeFormatter f = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendPattern("ddMM")
    .parseDefaulting(YEAR, currentYear)
    .toFormatter();
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("yourstring", f);
```

Or even better, the abovementioned formatter class supports **optional elements**. Wrap the year specifier in square brackets and the element will be optional. You can then supply a default with `parseDefaulting`.

Here is an example:

```
String s1 = "Oct 5 11:05:03";
String s2 = "Oct 5 1996 13:51:56"; // Year supplied
String format = "MMM d [uuuu ]HH:mm:ss";

DateTimeFormatter f = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendPattern(format)
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.YEAR, Year.now().getValue())
    .toFormatter(Locale.US);

System.out.println(LocalDate.parse(s1, f));
System.out.println(LocalDate.parse(s2, f));
```

---

*Note: Dates and times are not easy. You should take into consideration that date interpreting is often locale-dependant and this sometimes leads to ambiguity. For example, the date string "05/12/2018" means the 12th of May, 2018 when you are American, but in some European areas it means the 5th of December 2018. You need to be aware of that.*

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to concatenate the current year onto the incoming date string, and then parse:

```
String ts = "Oct 10 11:05:03";
int currYear = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
ts = String.valueOf(currYear) + " " + ts;

Date date = getDate(ts, "yyyy MMM d HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(date);

Wed Oct 10 11:05:03 CEST 2018
```

### Demo

Note that we could have used `StringBuilder` above, but the purpose of brevity of code, I used raw string concatenations instead.  I also fixed a few typos in your helper method `getDate()`.